# Android Error while Syncing project with Gradle React Native

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, gradlew

i just started using my new M1 mac , environment setup done completely . while trying to sync project with Gradle i am getting following error :

```
Null extracted folder for artifact: ResolvedArtifact(componentIdentifier=com.facebook.react:react-native:0.66.4, variantName=null
```

and here is my env info :

```
System:
    OS: macOS 12.5
    CPU: (10) arm64 Apple M1 Max
    Memory: 26.88 GB / 64.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 18.6.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.16.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2022.07.04.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 21.4, iOS 15.5, macOS 12.3, tvOS 15.4, watchOS 8.5
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2021.2 AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683
    Xcode: 13.4.1/13F100 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.16 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2 
    react-native: 0.66.4 => 0.66.4
```

and when i run through `npx react-native run-android` i got the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform react-native-0.66.4.aar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.66.4) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for ExtractAarTransform: /Users/username/project'sfolder/node_modules/react-native/android/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.66.4/react-native-0.66.4.aar.
         > Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
```